Can't unlock file on mac
On my mac I can't edit ~/.ssh/known_hosts manually because it is locked. Right-click -> Get Info, the "Locked" radio button is not clicked, but the file still remains locked: attemps to manually edit it in TextEdit result in a pop-up window appearing saying:

The file "known_hosts" is locked. If you want to make changes to this document, click unlock.

Clicking "unlock" in the pop-up window produces another pop-up window which says:

The file "known_hosts" cannot be unlocked. You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate.

When I cd to .ssh folder, these commands in terminal have also failed to unlock the file:
$ sudo chflags nouchg,noschg "~/.ssh/known_hosts"
$ sudo chflags nouchg,noschg ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ sudo chflags nouchg,noschg "known_hosts"
$ sudo chflags nouchg,noschg known_hosts

ls -l ~/.ssh/known_hosts yields -rw-r--r--@ 3 Baz  staff  4779  3 Jun  2016 /Users/Baz/.ssh/known_hosts
I don't know where to go next. How do I unlock ~/.ssh/known_hosts?

I'm not sure to be honest, but did you try to unlock them recursively? Try using sudo chflags -R nouchg ~/.ssh/known_hosts... Also you don't need to put the directory in quotation marks (" "). Finally, noschg is only for changing system files (although this shouldn't be possible in macOS Big Sur or later without disabling SIP, breaking the Signed System Volume and mounting the system volume to make changes to system files), whereas nouchg is for user files, so you can drop noschg from your command

@AVelj it is a simply file, recursive doesn‘t change anything.

What do xattr -l ~/.ssh/known_hosts and whoami show?

I'd recommend that you simply recreate the file, that is, duplicate it, delete the original and rename the copy. As to why the file can't be unlocked... hard to say,... I had a similar problem a while ago, and I suspect that, under some circumstances, using an app like TextEdit to edit a text file that was not explicitly created by an app may cause the file to get locked.

Why do you want to edit the file ? YOu should use ssh-keygen to remove some fqdn's if needed.

@0stone0 not sure this helps if the file is locked.

Might be locked by using weird programs to alter the file. After OP's problem is fixed ssh-keygen is a lot easier ;)

The file seems to have extended attributes set, which may prevent editing. Run
xattr -c ~/.ssh/known_hosts

to remove them.
